# Scale adaption based on distance to object

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, monogame

I have situation illustrated on image above, name displayed over the player. Text is rendered as 3d rectangle and rotated to face camera as billboard. (I am using this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2011/01/12/spritebatch-billboards-in-a-3d-world.aspx) I just want to have size of the text always the same.
Are there any common approach to adaptively scale object based on distance?

[image: Scale problem]

Comment: Draw your text as a screen space overlay rather than an object that is being transformed from an alternate coordinate system.

Answer (score 1):

Objects in 3D space are transformed using world/view/projection matrices to give positions in projection space. You should be familiar with these from using `BasicEffect`.

You can use these matrices yourself to transform a position into projection space:

```
Matrix transform = (worldMatrix * viewMatrix * projMatrix);
Vector3 modelAttachPoint = Vector3.Zero; // where you want the label, in model space
Vector3 projPosition = Vector3.Transform(modelAttachPoint, transform);
```

Projection space runs from (-1,-1) in the bottom left corner of the viewport, to (1,1) in the top right (and from 0 to 1 on the Z axis for depth).

We could use simple maths to convert our projected position into pixel coordinates. But it's even easier to just take the matrix that `SpriteBatch` uses to go from pixel coordinates to projected coordinates, and invert it.

Fortunately - that very article you linked gives us the `SpriteBatch` projection matrix:

```
Viewport viewport = GraphicsDevice.Viewport;
Matrix spriteBatchMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(-0.5f, -0.5f, 0) * 
    Matrix.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0, viewport.Width, viewport.Height, 0, 0, 1);
```

And we can use it like so:

```
Vector3 pixelPosition = Vector3.Transform(projPosition, spriteBatchMatrix.Invert());
```

Of course, that position won't necessarily line up with pixel boundaries (which you want for nice, sharp text). Also it has an unnecessary Z-coordinate. So let's finish up with something you can pass into `SpriteBatch`:

```
Vector2 spritePosition = new Vector2((float)Math.Floor(pixelPosition.X), 
                                     (float)Math.Floor(pixelPosition.Y));
```

(Note: code in this answer is completely untested!)